# How to arrange the layout of frames with navigation bar

Tags: python, layout, matplotlib, tkinter

What I want is simple but drove me crazy. For some reason I can't create a frame for buttons and tree structure that are not attached to navigation toolbar. What I have is:

[image]

and what I want is

[image]

Here is the code segment:

```
import os, ttk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg

from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from Tkinter import * 
import Tkinter, tkFileDialog, tkMessageBox
from numpy import arange, sin, pi, genfromtxt 

import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
   import Tkinter as Tk
else:
    import tkinter as Tk

root = Tk.Tk()
root.wm_title("Particle Counter")
fig= Figure(figsize = (10,7), dpi =100) # window size
fig.suptitle('Nanobiz Particle Counter', fontsize = 14, fontweight = 'bold')

ax1=fig.add_subplot(211) # figure adds this. later figure is added to canvas.
ax1.set_title('0.5u Particle',fontsize = 10)
ax1.set_xlabel('Time',fontsize = 10)
ax1.set_ylabel('Particle Number',fontsize = 10)   
ax1.set_ylim([0,6000])
ax1.xaxis.set_label_coords(1,-0.09)
ax1.plot(array1)

ax2=fig.add_subplot(212)
ax2.set_title('5u Particle',fontsize = 10)
ax2.set_xlabel('Time',fontsize = 10)
ax2.xaxis.set_label_coords(1,-0.09)
ax2.set_ylim([0,6000])
ax2.set_ylabel('Particle Number',fontsize = 10)
ax2.plot(array2)
ax2.grid()

mainFrame = Frame(root)
mainFrame.pack()

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, mainFrame)


#canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', on_key_event)

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, root)
toolbar.update()
toolbar.pack()
canvas.show()
canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=Tk.LEFT, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.LEFT, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
aboutMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="About",menu=aboutMenu, command = about_)
#aboutMenu.pack(side=Tk.RIGHT)


buttonFrame = Frame(root)
buttonFrame.pack(side = Tk.BOTTOM)


closeButton = Tk.Button(buttonFrame, text='Close', width = 6, command=_quit)
closeButton.pack(side= RIGHT)
```

Thanks

Comment: I've added the [tag:tkinter] and [tag:matplotlib] tags because it looks like you're using both, if this is incorrect then please re-edit them :) adding tags helps people to narrow down what they're interested in and is likely to get you more help sooner.

Comment: Thank you. You are right, Navigation toolbar is used with matplotlib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `canvas` in `mainFrame` but you add `NavigationToolbar` to `root`

Use `mainFrame` in place of `root` in

```
toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, mainFrame)
```

and you get button `Close` below `NavigationToolbar`

To get `NavigationToolbar` above `canvas` use

```
toolbar.pack(side=Tk.TOP)
```

---

**EDIT:** as for Tree - do you need this on left of `NavigationToolbar` and `buttonFrame` or below `NavigationToolbar` and above `buttonFrame` ?

As for me - it is easer to do it all with `.grid(row=...,column=...)` then with `.pack()`

Comment: I did what you suggested and it works (used pack for now). Thank you for the answer. As for Tree, I need it below toolbar and above button frame.